# Kubernetes: kubectl run: command not found

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, kubectl

I was running kubectl command to deploy my application in the gcloud. But suddenly the kubectl command stopped working. `kubectl` command is working fine but for everything else it say command not found.

`kubectl create
bash: kubectl create: command not found`

`kubectl run
bash: kubectl run: command not found`

```
SBGML02586:~ mku01$ kubectl
kubectl controls the Kubernetes cluster manager. 

Find more information at: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/

Basic Commands (Beginner):
  create         Create a resource from a file or from stdin.
  expose         Take a replication controller, service, deployment or pod and
expose it as a new Kubernetes Service
  run            Run a particular image on the cluster
  set            Set specific features on objects......
```

Comment: What do you get if you run `echo $PATH`

Comment: it is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: @user1529891 you can see the edited question, kubectl is installed correctly.

Comment: `which kubectl
/usr/local/bin/kubectl`

Comment: Can you run `strace -f kubectl run` or something like that (and add output to the question)? It really looks like your shell might not be handling spaces and somehow it thinks the whole `kubectl\ run` file is a program name.

Comment: Also please list `gcloud version` in your question.

Comment: can you add kubectl version?

Comment: I think my local file system might have corrupted, so am thinking to remove everything and reinstall again.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I had a similar error when I was setting up Kubernetes on Linux for the first time:

When I try to run the commands:

```
kubectl cluster-info
kubectl version
```

I get the error:

```
-bash: kubectl: command not found
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

Download the latest Kubernetes release with the command:

```
curl -LO "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
```

Make the kubectl binary executable:

```
chmod +x ./kubectl
```

Move the binary in to your PATH:

```
sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

Test to ensure the version you installed is up-to-date:

```
kubectl cluster-info
kubectl version
```

You can read up more about it in the Kubernetes Official Docs: [Install and Set Up kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/)

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: I think its important to mention to new people starting using Kubernetes(like me..) that this comands should be run from a different account than root, with privileges of sudo. In my case I was blocked at the start just because I was running the installation as root.

Comment: Good solution with clear explanation, many thanks

Answer (score 9):

I got this message while using wsl on windows. `kubectl` was working but suddenly started showing the same error

```
/mnt/c/Users/xxxx$ kubectl
kubectl: command not found
```

The issue was that docker was not started after I had restarted my laptop

```
:/usr/local/bin$ ls -ltr
total 2548
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     221 Sep 18  2020 pip3.8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     221 Sep 18  2020 pip3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     221 Sep 18  2020 pip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     208 Sep 18  2020 wheel
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2592768 Apr  5 10:57 kubectx
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      55 May 24 11:22 kubectl -> /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools/usr/local/bin/kubect
```

It started working once I started my docker application (I use docker-desktop for windows, and I had disabled auto-start on startup)

Answer (score 5):

Homebrew users might fix it with:

```
brew reinstall kubectl
```

May need to follow it with:

```
brew link --overwrite kubernetes-cli
```

Comment: Had to run `brew unlink kubernetes-cli && brew link kubernetes-cli` instead of `brew link --overwrite kubernetes-cli` but it helped, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your nix config file and add "kubernetes.enable = true;" in tools.

Answer (score 0):

kubectl is not available after enabling kubernetes in docker-desktop. Follow these steps to resolve the issue:

**First step:**
Download the latest release with the command:

```
curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
```

**Second step:**
Download the kubectl checksum file:

```
curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl.sha256"
```

Validate the kubectl binary against the checksum file:

```
echo "$(cat kubectl.sha256)  kubectl" | sha256sum --check
```

If valid, the output is:

```
kubectl: OK
```

If the check fails, sha256 exits with nonzero status and prints output similar to:

> Note: Download the same version of the binary and checksum.

**Third step:**

Install kubectl

```
sudo install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

**Fourth step:**

Test to ensure the version you installed is up-to-date:

```
kubectl version --client
```

or use this for detailed view of version:

```
kubectl version --client --output=yaml
```